# Upload file using PHP and FTP, where is my error?

Tags: php, ftp

Below code takes file from html form and saves temp file to local temp folder but cannot upload to server. Server will take upload from ftp client, but php code below returns "Cannot upload". Problem with $destDir? Directory exists on server... any help appreciated.

```
<?php
// set up basic connection
$ftp_server = "ftp.rf.gd";
$ftp_user_name = "rfgd_19026557";
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$pass="fakepass";
// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $pass);
//test if the connection is successful
echo '<center>';
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
if (!$conn_id)
    echo '<div style="background-color:red;padding:10px;color:#fff;font-size:16px;">
    Couldn\'t connect to <b>' . $ftp_server . '</b></div>';
else
    echo '<div style="background-color:green;padding:10px;color:#fff;font-size:16px;">
    Connected to <b>' . $ftp_server . '</b></div>';
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);  // turns on passive mode
// upload a file
$destDir = "Business/pics";
$workDir = "C:\Apache24\htdocs\Images"; // define this as per local system
// get temporary file name for the uploaded file
$tmpName = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]['tmp_name']);
// copy uploaded file into current directory
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $workDir."/".$tmpName) or die("Cannot move uploaded file to working directory");

//Code above this point works

// perform file upload
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destDir."/".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'], $workDir."/".$tmpName, FTP_BINARY);
// check upload status
// display message
if (!$upload) {
    echo "Cannot upload";
} else {
    echo "Upload complete";
}
// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
// delete local copy of uploaded file
//unlink($workDir."/".$tmpName) or die("Cannot delete uploaded file from working directory — manual deletion recommended");
?>
```

Comment: Do you have the permissions to initiate outgoing traffic?

Comment: I am running from browser address http://localhost/upload.html which asks for file input and calls the below php file. same folder (htdocs). What would I do to check for permission to go out?

Comment: Oops, found my mistake. After connecting, I redefine $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) again, which essentially disconnects. Sorry for the bother and thanks for looking to help.
Jeff

Answer (score 2):

```
$trackErrors = ini_get('track_errors');
ini_set('track_errors', 1);
if (!@ftp_put($conn_id, $destDir."/".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'], $workDir."/".$tmpName, FTP_BINARY)) {
   // error message is now in $php_errormsg
   $msg = $php_errormsg;
   ini_set('track_errors', $trackErrors);
   throw new Exception($msg);
}
```

Comment: <center><div style="background-color:green;padding:10px;color:#fff;font-size:16px;">
    Connected to <b>ftp.rf.gd</b></div><br />
<b>Warning</b>:  ftp_put() [<a href='/phpmanual/function.ftp-put'>function.ftp-put</a>]: You aren't logged in in <b>C:\Apache24\htdocs\newupload.php</b> on line <b>29</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Exception: ftp_put() [&lt;a href='/phpmanual/function.ftp-put'&gt;function.ftp-put&lt;/a&gt;]: You aren't logged in in C:\Apache24\htdocs\newupload.php:35
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\Apache24\htdocs\newupload.php</b> on line <b>35</b>

Comment: basic error: "You are not logged in"
Clearly I have logged in to the FTP server, as you can see the "Connected to ftp.rf.gd. in the output. Do I also need to login to my local apache server to run the html file that calls my php script? Cannot find anything online about this.

Thanks, Jeff